# axios.get.mockResolvedValue() is marked as problem in testfile.test.ts (Vue/Vitest)

Tags: vue.js, axios, mocking, vitest

I am currently in the process of integrating vitest into my Vue app. The unit tests run successfully.
However, I get an error message:
'*The property "mockResolvedValue" is for type "<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T, any>, D = any>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig | undefined) => Promise" unavailable. ts(2339)*'

At the beginning of the test file I have the following:

```
vi.mock('axios', () => {
    return {
        default: {
            get: vi.fn()
        }
    }
});
```

Now I want to use the mocked axios in my test() methods:

```
const mockedData = {
    "title": "Testtitle",
    "price": 13.98
}

test('Description', async () => {
    axios.get.mockResolvedValue({
        status: 200,
        data: mockedData
    });

    expect(await callFunctionToTest()).toStrictEqual(mockedData)
})
```

And that's where the problem occures.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: For your information:
It looks like as the problem only occurs if you use .ts file. I changed it to .js and it works well now.
Does anyone know how to get it running with .ts test file?

Comment: I had a similar problem, when trying to mock the `plyr` library in a Vue/Vite project. It seems like that the mocking is not working in vitest when packages are used with typescript and are inside Vue Single File Components. That would be my guess. I created an issue on vitest where you might want to add your problem as well? https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/issues/1484

Answer (score 1):

There is a helper `vi.mocked()` to resolve this issue with typescript.

https://vitest.dev/api/vi.html#vi-mocked

This should fix it:

```js
vi.mocked(axios.get).mockResolvedValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

For Svelte/ SvelteKit
Following the answer with vi.mocked(), what helped me to have a work around was:
only mock the response I expect to get from the function, i.e if i have a load function

```
// +page.server.ts
import { useApi } from '$lib/utils/api';
import { redirect } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import type { PageServerLoad } from './$types';

export const load: PageServerLoad = async () => {
    const properties = await useApi()
        .path.to.end.point.get({
            query: {
                query_id: 'string'
            }
        })
        .then((res) => res.body);
    return { properties };
};
```

i only mock the `load` function with the expected response,

```
//+page.server.test.ts 
import { describe, it, expect, vi } from 'vitest';
import { load } from './+page.server';
import type { PropertyListingResponse } from '$apitypes';

const properties: ApiResponse[] = vi.hoisted(() => [
    {
        response_id: '550e8411-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000',
        URL: 'https://website-media.com/assets/auth-background.png',
        name: 'Kit Apartments',
        location: 'Los Angeles',
        country: 'US'
    },
    {
        response_id: '550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655880000',
        URL: 'https://website-media.com/assets/auth-background.png',
        name: 'Kita Apartments',
        location: 'New York',
        country: 'US'
    }
]);
vi.mock('./+page.server.ts');
describe('properties-load', () => {
    it('returns a list of properties', async () => {
        vi.mocked(load).mockResolvedValue(properties);
        const result = (await load()) as Array<ApiResponse>;
        expect(result[0].name).toBe(properties[0].name);
    });
});
```

This works well for most cases, you can even mock with multiple responses if the funtion returns multiple outputs

Answer (score -2):

I don't know how to solve this problem with `*.test.ts` file but I solved it when using `*.test.js` file.

Comment: *TypeScript error? Solve your error by not using TypeScript.*